# No matter what I do I can't get my Javascript files to run on PhoneGap

Tags: cordova

This is my first time posting on here so here it goes. I have done some extensive research trying to find the answer to my problem. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. It seems that no matter what I do I can't get my Javascript files to run on my Phonegap appliation. Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title><a href="myapp.js"></a>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="myapp.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
            app.initialize();
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function onLoad(){
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
}

function onDeviceReady(){

    $(function(){

        $("body").append("<h1>DEVICE IS READY</h1>");
    });
}
</script>

</head>

<body onload="onLoad">

</body>
</html>
```

The working example that I was doing is located here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t95KG_SFppU

Here is my repository: https://github.com/AwakenStudio/myAndroidApp

Comment: +1 for icktoofay's answer.. You may also want to make sure that you have linked your JS file with the correct path.

Answer (score 2):

`onload` is some code that is run, not the name of a function. For that reason, you need parentheses after the function name.

```html
<body onload="onLoad();">
```

Also, while it shouldn't cause a problem, `a` elements go in the `body`, not in the `head`, so you should probably remove this:

```html
<a href="myapp.js"></a>
```

Comment: Even after I fix the onload="onLoad();" I still do not show anything.

Comment: I don't know if it was because I was mixing Javascript and jQuery in the same file, but after replacing the jQuery with this it worked fine: 

    function onDeviceReady(){
        
     alert("Device is ready");
    }

Comment: Now it seems though that if I try to use jQuery Mobile in my app the jQuery won't fire.

Comment: @PaulNeumyer: If there's an error console or anything, you should see if any errors show up, and if so, what. I've not used PhoneGap myself, so I don't know if there is or not.